# CSV Modification Python

Tags: python, pandas, csv, export-to-csv

I am having difficulties with the processing of a CSV File. I need a pythonic solution that reads a CSV with rows like:
[image: Excel Sheet]

And generates an output(preferably with the same CSV name) to produce this:
[image]

(All the header information like **Row1**, **Row2**, **Row3** should be removed and the value type row specifying **Number** should be removed as well)

Is some kind of pandas/python solution viable for this? I've been trying but to no avail.

Any guidance would also greatly help as I'm new to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this problem can sovle like that.

```
f = open("new.csv","w")
for line in open("sample.csv").readlines():
    temp = line.split(",").strip()
    if len(temp) < 4 : pass
    else :
        if temp[0] == "Number": pass
        else : f.write(line)
f.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick, using xlrd and xlwt:

```
import xlrd, xlwt, os

book = xlrd.open_workbook('Path to input file to read')
sheet = book.sheet_by_index(0)
nrows = sheet.nrows
ncols = sheet.ncols

outputs = []
for i in range(nrows):
    if str(sheet.cell(i,0).value).startswith('Row') or str(sheet.cell(i,0).value).startswith('Number'):
        continue
    else:
        outputs.append([sheet.cell(i,j).value for j in range(ncols)])

os.chdir('Path to save output file')
out = xlwt.Workbook()
sheet1 = out.add_sheet('Output')
for row, i in enumerate(outputs):
    for col, j in enumerate(i):
        sheet1.write(row, col, str(j))
out.save('out.xls')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import csv
with open('old.csv', newline='') as fr, open('new.csv', 'w', newline='') as fw:
    reader, writer = csv.reader(fr), csv.writer(fw)
    for row in reader:
       # skip rows until 'Value1'
       if row[0] == 'Value1':
           writer.writerow(row)
           break
    # skip type descriptions
    next(reader) 
    # write the rest of rows
    writer.writerows(list(reader))
```